# How many students play basketball and soccer?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A small school with 14 students has a basketball team with 5 players, a chess team with 4
players, a netball team with 7 players, and a soccer team with 11 players.

• Each student is on at least one of these teams and no student is on all four teams.

• Only one student, Hawa, is on three of the teams: she plays chess, netball and soccer.

• There is exactly 1 student who plays basketball and chess.

• There is exactly 1 student who plays basketball and netball.

• Hawa is the only student who plays chess and netball.

• There are exactly 3 students (including Hawa) who play chess and soccer.

• There are exactly 5 students (including Hawa) who play netball and soccer

How many students play basketball and soccer?

I did this manually and drew out the slots for each member in each team and I got 3 students.But I'm pretty sure there's a mathematical way of doing this using combinations perhaps.Can someone post the working?

Comment: You'll have to represent the teams as sets and probably use the fact that $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$ multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

We can verify your answer by using the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Let $B$, $C$, $N$, and $S$ denote, respectively, the set of students who play basketball, chess, netball, and soccer.

If we apply the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to these four sets, we obtain
\begin{align*}
|B \cup C \cup N \cup S| & = |B| + |C| + |N| + |S|\\
                         & \quad - |B \cap C| - |B \cap N| - |B \cap S| - |C \cap N| - |C \cap S| - |N \cap S|\\
                         & \quad + |B \cap C \cap N| + |B \cap C \cap S| + |B \cap N \cap S| - |C \cap N \cap S|\\
                         & \quad - |B \cap C \cap N \cap S|\\
\end{align*}
We are told the following information:

- A small school with $14$ students has a basketball team with $5$ players $\implies |B| = 5$, a chess team with $4$ players $\implies |C| = 4$, a netball team with $7$ players $\implies |N| = 7$, and a soccer team with $11$ players $\implies |S| = 11$.
- Each student is on at least one of these teams $\implies |B \cup C \cup N \cup S| = 14$ and no student is on all four teams $\implies |B \cap C \cap N \cap S| = 0$.
- Only one student, Hawa, is on three of the teams: she plays chess, netball and soccer $\implies |C \cap N \cap S| = 1$ and $|B \cap C \cap N| = |B \cap C \cap S| = |B \cap N \cap S| = 0$.
- There is exactly 1 student who plays basketball and chess $\implies |B \cap C| = 1$.
- There is exactly 1 student who plays basketball and netball $\implies |B \cap N| = 1$.
- Hawa is the only student who plays chess and netball $\implies |C \cap N| = 1$.
- There are exactly 3 students (including Hawa) who play chess and soccer $\implies |C \cap S| = 3$.
- There are exactly 5 students (including Hawa) who play netball and soccer $\implies |N \cap S| = 5$.

Substituting this information into the above formula gives
\begin{align*}
14 & = 5 + 4 + 7 + 11 - 1 - 1 - |B \cap S| - 1 - 3 - 5 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 - 0\\
14 & = 17 - |B \cap S|\\
|B \cap S| & = 3
\end{align*}
as you found.